# Get Notified about Windows is Going to Sleep/Waking up in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on an App which has Multiple Threads waiting for different inputs from DLLs and Serial Ports.

I want to add a functionality that before machine going to Sleep, I have to unload certain DLL and On waking up have to  Re-load the DLL.
For this, I need to get notified on Sleep and Wake up.

I found many files about doing in C# but I want to do this in C++.

I tried using this [code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/OSEvents.aspx) but could not capture any event. I removed everything related to Window Paint and All that as I do not need it's GUI and kept only `main message loop (The While loop in the main)`

EDIT:-

I am using this as my main loop:-

```
 // Start the message loop. 

while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}
```

To be frank I have copied this from CodeProject, and Made only one Modification i.e. Checked GetMessage(..) != 0 from a MSDN Article.

Am I missing something?

Or anyother Solution??

I am using VS2010 and programming in C++

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is the difference if someone is closing your programm (WM_CLOSE) and shutting down the system?

Comment: @RedX I haven't handled this event but the DLL unloads in the case of Close or Shutdown as the process gets killed.

Comment: Oh, ignore my message. Sleep not shutdown.

Comment: Showing us your message loop would be quite helpful in this case.

Comment: What does TranslateMessage do and where did you catch WM_PAINT and other similar events? Where you parse WM_PAINT you need to catch WM_POWERBROADCAST and there check for the PBT_* events. Maybe you should search for an introduction into WINAPI and window message loop before proceeding.

Comment: @RedX Thanks for Guiding me! and Sorry for Asking Stupid questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try handling the [WM_POWERBROADCAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa373247) message

Here's sample code that should work. Apparently you do need to create a window otherwise you don't receive the messages. The sample creates a hidden window to achieve this.

```
static long FAR PASCAL WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(message == WM_POWERBROADCAST)
    {
        //Do something
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WNDCLASS wc = {0};


    // Set up and register window class
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = _T("SomeNameYouInvented");
    RegisterClass(&wc);
    HWND hWin = CreateWindow(_T("SomeNameYouInvented"), _T(""), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);

    BOOL bRet;
    MSG msg;
    while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hWin, 0, 0 )) != 0)
    { 
        if (bRet == -1)
        {
            // handle the error and possibly exit
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg); 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes...I got that... but can't understand how to do it... I'm newbie with C++ and WINAPIs....

Comment: When you register your window using RegisterClass function you specify your the [windowproc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The parameter uMsg in the windowproc function you wrote is the one you should test if it's WM_POWERBROADCAST.

Comment: and What if I don't have any window or GUI?? I am building an app which runs in background without User Intervention :(

Comment: If you don't create a window, don't use translate/dispatch and compare the value of msg.message to WM_POWERBROADCAST.

Comment: But I have use RegisterClass to specify my WndProc function. So What Should I pass to RegisterClass if I don't have any window?

Comment: You only need RegisterClass if you want to create a window. In your case that isn't necessary. After you called GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0), the contents you need are in the msg structure. Remove the translate and dispatch in your code sample above and replace it with a check on msg.message == WM_POWERBROADCAST.

Comment: My code is not getting out of GetMessage() or I can say, It is not getting any messages so it is keep waiting there!