# How to receive notification when Windows wakes up displays from the sleep mode?

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to handle a situation when Windows wakes up displays from the sleep mode, but when OS not in sleep mode itself. This situation happens when the user was inactive for some time and the OS put the display into sleep mode for power saving. And after some time user wakes up, and the OS switch on the display.

This behavior adjusted in power options, like on the screenshot below:
[image]

I was hoping to get a notification from the OS in `WindowProc` functions, but this approach doesn't work. Maybe need to register such kind of notifications by some function like `WTSRegisterSessionNotification`.

Comment: Will [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/power/system-wake-up-events) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo) help?

Comment: The software received WM_POWERBROADCAST message only when OS wake-up from the sleep mode, but not for display sleep model. Also, software received some unknown message 0xC280 when the display was switched off or on, but I can't find any information about this type of message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerpowersettingnotification) together with the [power guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Power/power-setting-guids) `GUID_SESSION_DISPLAY_STATUS`.

Comment: And this approach works fine in Windows 7, but in the documentation noticed that it started from Windows 8

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `WM_POWERBROADCAST` message

Like this case:

[Get Notified about Windows is Going to Sleep/Waking up in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253714/get-notified-about-windows-is-going-to-sleep-waking-up-in-c)

Comment: This approach works only for OS sleep mode, but not works for display sleep mode.

Comment: @ramzes2 
Do you mean to get notifications of sleep and wake up on the display?

Comment: Yes, I want to get notification of the display power mode changes (for example, wake up from the sleep mode)

Comment: @ramzes2 you can refer this article.. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1193099/Determining-the-Monitors-On-Off-sleep-Status