# Handling сonnections: suspending and resuming it on laptop sleep and network interface сhanges in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, network-programming

I am working on an application that establishes a UDP connection to a host and maintains it. I encounter difficulties when dealing with scenarios such as the laptop going to sleep and waking up, or when the user switches from a wired to a wireless connection (or vice versa). Specifically, I need to pause and resume the UDP connection accordingly.

Initially, my approach involved querying [`GetBestRoute2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-getbestroute2) with the UDP host's IP address before establishing the connection. I then retrieved the `NetworkGuid` by querying [`GetIfEntry2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-getifentry2) with the interface index obtained from the previous step. Subsequently, I used events from the [Network List Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetworkevents-networkconnectivitychanged) (NLM) to wait for updates related to the matching GUID.

However, it appears that NLM uses its own set of GUIDs, seemingly unrelated to the `NetworkGuid` obtained from `GetIfEntry2`. As a result, I'm at a loss on how to proceed.

Is there a reliable way to correlate the information from `GetIfEntry2` with NLM events, or are there alternative methods to achieve the desired behavior?

**Update:** Potential Solution Found

It seems I may have found a solution, although it doesn't feel optimal to me. Before establishing the UDP connection, I now also invoke `GetBestRoute2` and `GetIfEntry2`, but instead of using `NetworkGuid` for correlation, I utilize `InterfaceGuid`. As it turns out, this GUID is equivalent to the value obtainable through the `INetworkConnection::GetAdapterId` method (NLM). Consequently, I now query `GetNetworkConnections` instead of `GetNetworks`, requesting `GetAdapterId` for each connection. If the obtained value matches `InterfaceGuid`, the connection belongs to the desired network. Following this, I invoke `GetNetwork` and, finally, `GetNetworkId` for the acquired network. Finally I can construct a set of `NetworkId`.

Subsequently, during event monitoring, I could check this set if it was an active connection. If not, I ignore the event; if it was, I take the necessary actions—either pausing or resuming the connection. Upon resumption, I create a new set to update information about the active connection.

But I'm concerned about the efficiency and reliability of this solution.

Comment: What kind of "connection" are you establishing, exactly? UDP is *connection-less*! Just let the OS decide the best route for each packet you want to send.

Comment: ... And then have some kind of mechanism to check if it got through (which is not easy) so that you can resend it if necessary.

Comment: @RemyLebeau To be precise I am using OpenVPN3 library. It has pause and resume methods. It's pretty useful to stop it from trying to establish connection while laptop is in sleep or don't have internet connection at all. Otherwise it will continue trying to reconnect forever. Also it has hardcoded 5 seconds delay, but I want to pause and resume instantly after sleep or network change.

Comment: For macOS they implemented MacLifeCycle class (https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3/blob/master/openvpn/apple/maclife.hpp), so in case of Macs OpenVPN3 works flawlessly -- it pauses during sleep and resumes after it -- all automatically.

So I want this kind of logic for Windows.

Comment: If you like the library on your Mac OS X, then use the Windows version for your Windows OS. From the Git repository: "_OpenVPN 3 is currently used in production as the core of the OpenVPN Connect clients for iOS, Android, Linux, **Windows**, and Mac OS X._"

Comment: @RonMaupin I am using the same library on both Windows and macOS, but it behaves differently on those OS. That's why I want to port this logic to Windows.

Comment: Windows has a mechanism for informing applications when it's about to go to sleep and when it wakes up, does that help?  Some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253714/get-notified-about-windows-is-going-to-sleep-waking-up-in-c

Comment: @PaulSanders I would try, thanks! It will cover the case with sleeps. But still: how to handle the case when user is changing network (eth -> wifi, vice versa)?

Comment: @savely Sorry, I don't know about that.  Is it disruptive?  If network access disappears entirely then it obviously is, but ethernet <-> wifi sounds like it should 'just work', especially if you're using UDP.

Comment: @SavelyKrasovsky you already know the answer to that (NLM events). But, if you are specify a target host on each UDP packet, then Windows should just route it automatically by default based on the best available interface at the time. Are you binding your sending socket to a specific interface?

Comment: @PaulSanders it should be probably yes in case of plain UDP, but for some reason OpenVPN3 needs to reestablish connection again, otherwise.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have updated my question with the possible solution. It even works as I need, but it seems clunky.

Comment: It would be better to post that as code (or pseudo code), as an answer to your own question.  (That's allowed, might get upvoted)

Comment: @SavelyKrasovsky see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for links, I answered my question!

Comment: @PaulSanders I didn't post the code, but I guess it's comprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `INetworkConnectionEvent` and `INetworkListManagerEvents` are more suitable for my needs. The first one gives me events about specific physical connections (compared to `INetworkEvents`, which is about abstract networks), and the second one provides general events about network connectivity.

This approach helps me handle two situations:

1. Events about overall internet connectivity let me pause/resume the OpenVPN3 connection.
2. Specific connection events allow me to pause/resume the connection when the active interface changes.

Here's the simplified algorithm:

1. Get the interface index used for connecting to the host using `GetBestRoute2`.
2. Obtain the interface GUID using `GetIfEntry2` and save it; it indicates the interface that will be used to connect the host.
3. Wait for events; if you receive a `DISCONNECTED` event, pause the connection; if you receive an event about restoring internet connectivity, resume the connection AND update currently active interface by repeating first two steps.

I could not add some code here, because in my case I am using my own Golang bindings to C++ and it's a little bit scary to show it currently, so I decided to at least describe my final solution.

Comment: Good job, well worth adding this.